# Is there any way to create Magento Bundle product option dependent with another option group?

Tags: bundle, magento2.3.5-p1, magento2bundleproduct

I have a bundle product with multiple Options Groups Like
Option group A, group B, group C.

Now when user select product from group B then user can not select product from group C and vise-versa.

Please suggest me and help me on this.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.magento.com/folio3ecommerce-module-productsdependency.html#bazaarvoice.reviews.tab

Might be useful for someone who has the same requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I have already created as per my requirement. It was developed 1 year ago.

Comment: The extension was last updated on 12 July, 2023 and works perfectly for me on latest version of magento as of today.

Comment: https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/folio3ecommerce-module-productsdependency.html